# sbt: How do you set the value of publishTo for just one task?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'd like to create a task that publishes to a specific directory.  I tried this:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object SampleStuff extends Plugin {
  lazy val someCmd = taskKey[Unit]("some command")
  val someCmdValue = publishTo in someCmd := Some(Resolver.file("file",  new File( "path/to/my/maven-repo/releases")))
  override def settings = Seq(
    someCmdValue,
    someCmd := { println(s"publishing to the place; ${publish.value}") }
  )
}
```

I thought that the *publishTo in someCmd* would set the value of publishTo while someCmd was being executed, but that's not what happens.  What am I missing?